# Visual Studio indents CSS like the blocks never close

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

So this is a weird issue. I use Visual Studio with ReSharper Ultimate and when I edit some CSS, the indentation is all weird. It's like I'm missing closing a block, but this happens with all CSS files. My SCSS files are fine and are indented as they are supposed to.

[image]

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about. If I paste the code into any online beautifier or my Atom IDE, it indents everything just fine. What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By formatting it like this, VS is trying to visualize the element hierarchy. There's basically one indentation level per nested element. There's a setting to disable this behavior under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Advanced -> Hierarchical indentation.

Comment: That fixed it! Wow, why would they even do that? Thanks!

Comment: No idea why it's there. It's one of the first things I disable after a clean install.

Comment: Ah, I see why they do that now. It's obviously because, in this example, `.fifth` is the parent, which has children. That makes sense, but man is it annoying to look at.